# Arduino Sketches supposedly compiling/uploading but doesn't seem to be working when checking COM ports with Putty

Tags: compilation, serial-port, arduino, putty

I'm just starting out with the arduino uno and I've got a program previously loaded on which receives information from a bunch of sensors and outputs the received information through serial. So when I connect from COM3 (as on my computer) to the UNO with putty it outputs the sensors readings.

But I'm having an issue now with resetting the UNO with an empty sketch with just

```
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

when I upload the above it says compiled but when I connect with putty the old program seems to be still active?.

Any idea as to what is going wrong here?

Comment: There is the posibility that this program is empty so nothing is being uploaded (highly unlikely I know but Murphy's law and all).  Try uploading the blink sketch just to be sure.

Comment: @cstrutton I tried a few of the other examples too but still doesn't seem to work. Tried the blink sketch a the fade sketch.

Comment: Something is confusing me here.  Are you using the arduino IDE?  If so why are you using putty.  If not, why not?

Comment: @cstrutton Oh sorry I forgot to mention, I am using the arduino IDE, the reason I'm using putty is because I'm using a wifly board (RN-XV) to transmit data over wifi so I'm using putty to set it up

Comment: Did you check the IDE logs for any hint?

Comment: You could also try setting `upload.verbose` in the preferences file to get detailed messages from avrdude.  You could try to use avrdude from the command line as well.  Let me know how you make out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you close putty before uploading as it will probably block the commication between the IDE and the Arduino.

Also check not just for compilation, but also for uploading. Use the serial from the Arduino IDE during development. The compilation process knows how to kill that, and will do that automatically.